# My mesh, triangles and sphere?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, topology

I created this piece but I'd like to delete triangles to have a perfect result and use a Subsurf.
How I could to do to improve my mesh ?

[image]

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be easier if you shared your file, but maybe you should choose another topology at the beginning, i.e. a cube that you subdivide instead of a UV sphere:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

Something that worked for me when editing the mesh of a character after applying a skin modifier was to add an edge loop wherever possible around tri-faces.

Basically add an edge loop in the quads next to the tri face, and *poof*, you have quads there. You can adjust the edgeloops' locations by <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> to select, and the <kbd>G</kbd> key twice to move.